# JPA pagination for different methods

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to implement pagination for any other method except `findAll(pageable)` ?
For example, if I have my own method like `findByNameOrAge`:

```
public interface JPAPersonDAO extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
  List<Person> findByNameOrAge(String name, int age);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible .

```
Page<Person> findByNameOrAge(String name, int age,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did not know that I can use such constructor. This is exactly what I need.